# What are function signatures in ABIv2 and how do they enhance Ethereum?

Tags: abi, encoding

[EIP-712](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-712.md) talks about function signatures being `bytes4`. I understand that the new version of the ABI format will contain a pre-defined set of `keccak256` hashes of function names, as per the work done on [clef](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/clef/4byte.json), but it's not clear to me what their role is, in details.

What if there's a function not defined in that list? Will developers need to retrofit it for their apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function signature (which is a 4 bytes code) is used internally in solidity to call the function. However for a user interface to show the user some readable information it is useful to lookup the function name, which can be done via https://www.4byte.directory.
Clef integrates the entire 4bytes database to provide the same information.

Developers can add new functions via https://www.4byte.directory/import-solidity

Clef also has the option: --4bytedb-custom value to add new functions

---

Suppose you have function:

```
function setA(uint256 _a) { a = _a; }
```

Then the function signature is calculated with:

```
keccak("setA(uint256)")
```

Using https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html, this calculates to:
ee919d50445cd9f463621849366a537968fe1ce096894b0d0c001528383d4769

Taking the first 8 characters (=4 bytes), this results in (hex):
0xee919d50.
This is stored in a 4 byte-database, as can be seen here:

```
https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0xee919d50
ID      Text Signature  Bytes Signature
90738   setA(uint256)   0xee919d50
```

Also see:

- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/clef/README.md
- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/signer/fourbyte/4byte.json
- https://swende.se/blog/EVM-Assembly-trick.html
- https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/07/10/geth-v1-9-0