# What is a good use case for .call functions' ability to pass a function call?

Tags: web3js, security

Following up on [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96685/how-to-use-address-call-in-solidity/148874?noredirect=1#comment167122_148874) thread, I wish to understand what will be a good use case using the feature to call a function in .call{}() ?

Answer (score 0):

One use case is for wallet contracts. For example a multi signature wallet contract. The contract owner should be able to call any contract with any message.

Similarly flash loans contracts could allow the requester to execute any contract and message after receiving the loan.

Comment: Is it possible to call multiple functions through a single `call()`? As in multisig, when you need to say - attain confirmation from multiple wallets.

Comment: @MrigendraSoni Using a regular `address.call(message)`, it is not possible. It sends one message to one address. However a it is possible to implement a 'multicall'contract, that accepts one message and split it into multiple calls.